# Jesrsey @Path working mechanism

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I noticed a class in some sample somewhere the following methods were was implemented

```
@Path("{id}")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void retrieve(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                                 @PathParam("id") final String id) {....}
```

and

```
  @Path("/{id}")
  @GET
  @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
  public EventOutput retrieveSSE(@PathParam("id") final String id,@Context final HttpHeaders headers) {...}
```

Seems like the path is the same for both.
In this case what would happen? If my understanding is right based on the 'Accept' header from the client, the relevant method would be called.

If the Accept header is not mentioned, then what happens here?
Would both the methods be called? Or just the first method as it is in the beginning?

How does jersey decide which method to be called if Accept Header is not added?

Also even if the header is specified are both the functions called?? And it is the functions duty to respond to whether the given header is available or not.

I.E if the API call is made with Accept header as application/json

Are both methods called however since the first method has the mechanism to handle JSON it responds?

Do correct me if I've even asked the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the api call is made with accept header as application/json the first method will respond as it is meant to handle JSON request.
about your question on if the accept header is not mentioned and the resources have same paths then Jersey will probably give an error if your request is such where multiple resources might respond.

Comment: The weird thing was, the application responded with the JSON format even when the Accept Header was not present.